# Why Q# does not detect either F# or C# namespace?

Tags: c#, f#, q#

I am making a library in Q# and trying to add a project reference to an F# (or C#) library written by me. But it does not work.

After adding the appropriate reference, I checked my Q# project .csproj file and I could see that the reference was added there that means the process of adding was done properly. But when I try to run the code I receive this message: "error QS6104: No namespace with that name exists" which refers to the line including the name of that F# (or C#) library. I wonder why it happens. Is it due to some fundamental differences between Q# and F# but Q# is created based on F# and C# therefore is there any solution to solve the problem?
Here is my code snippet:

```
    namespace MyQSharpLibrary
    {
        open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
        open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;
        open MyFSharpLib;
        ...
        ...
    }
```

MyFSharpLib is the library I defined in F# and after adding reference to it inside "MyQSharpLibrary" I can see following markdown code in MyQSharpLibrary.csproj :

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      ...
      ...
       <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\MyFSharpLib\MyFSharpLib.fsproj"/>
       </ItemGroup>  
    </Project>
```

But after running MyQSharpLibrary, I receive error message: 
"error QS6104: No namespace with that name exists"
which refers to the line containing "open MyFSharpLib;"

Comment: Could you please share a small code sample that reproduces the behavior? It is unclear from the question what exactly you're trying to do. If you try to run C# or F# code directly from Q#, that is not supported. You can modify the simulator you're using to do that for you, but that's not straightforward.

Comment: Code snippet is shared now, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`open` directives in Q# only allow you to import Q# code, not F# or C# code. Q# does not in general allow execution of arbitrary classical code, since it is designed to be executed on a quantum device which in general might not have this ability.

---

If you're looking for a workaround that can be done in a simulation but will not be portable to a quantum device, you can write a simulator that extends one of the existing ones and exposes new intrinsic functions to Q# code that implement your classical computation.

For example, take a look at what the Quantum Katas do to gather statistics about the program execution: they define [CounterSimulator](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/utilities/Common/CounterSimulator.cs) which implements intrinsic functions such as `GetOracleCallsCount`, and a matching Q# code in [Utils.qs](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/utilities/Common/Utils.qs) which exposes them to Q# code. Then this project is added as a dependency to the katas that need this functionality, for example, [DeutschJozsaAlgorithm](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/tree/master/DeutschJozsaAlgorithm) - you'll see the project reference in [DeutschJozsaAlgorithm.csproj](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/DeutschJozsaAlgorithm/DeutschJozsaAlgorithm.csproj) file and a matching `open Quantum.Kata.Utils;` in [Tests.qs](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/DeutschJozsaAlgorithm/Tests.qs).

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful. But one more question, what does "body intrinsic" do? For instance, in Utils.qs there is :         operation GetMaxQubitCount () : Int { body intrinsic; }

Comment: This keyword means that the operation is not implemented in Q# code, but rather directly in a simulator (which is exactly the scenario you want)

Comment: When I run the program I receive this error message: `Cannot create an instance of QSharpLib because it is an abstract class.` where "QSharpLib" in my program is similar to Utils.qs in Quantum.Kata.Utils. So, how can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I'd need to see the code to answer that, it's not an error I've seen recently enough to recognize it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have created a question about it with the code snippets as well. Please have a look at : (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58784924/how-to-resolve-unhandled-exception-system-aggregateexception-error-in-q)

Comment: @MariiaMykhailova this is a strange design. How Sin from Microsoft.Quantum.Extensions.Math is essentially different from Sin from C#? Sin is a Sin, if you know what I mean :)

Comment: (I didn't do this design, but from what I heard...) Sin is not a great example, since the computation done by it is very fast (which is why Q# libraries have a function for it). But arbitrary C# code can do very time-consuming things like accessing a database or a web service endpoint. Since Q# is designed to eventually run on a quantum computer, the code has to be executed fast enough for the device to stay coherent while it's running; waiting for arbitrary code to finish is too slow.

Comment: I think if it turns out that there is a compelling enough reason to support running arbitrary C# code from Q# on a real device, this feature will be added, but so far no such reason has been identified.