# How to write C# implementation for a Q# operation with intrinsic body?

Tags: q#

I have created a library in C# to be used in Q# programs. The library has two scripts, a C# class library called "Class1.cs" and a matching Q# script called "Util.qs", I share the code snippet of each here:

Class1.cs:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Common;
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core;
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Simulators;

namespace MyLibrary {
    class Class1 : QuantumSimulator {

        static void Method_1 (string str) { ... }
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Util.qs:

```
namespace MyLibrary {
    operation Op_1 (str : String)  : Unit { body intrinsic; }
}
```

There is another Q# program in a different namespace that uses the namespace "MyLibrary" so after adding reference, in this Q# program I have:

```
namespace QSharp
{
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;

    open MyLibrary;

    operation TestMyLibrary() : Unit {
        Op_1("some string");
    }
}
```

When I execute "dotnet run" in the terminal I receive this message:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors
occurred. (Cannot create an instance of MyLibrary.Op_1 because it is
an abstract class.) ---> System.MemberAccessException: Cannot create
an instance of MyLibrary.Op_1 because it is an abstract class.
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Following Mariia' answer and also checking Quantum.Kata.Utils, I changed my code as following:

So, I changed Class1 script to:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Common;
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core;
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Simulators;

namespace MyLibrary {
    class Class1 : QuantumSimulator {

        private string classString = "";

        public Class1() { }

        public class Op_1_Impl : Op_1{

            string cl_1;

            public Op_1_Impl (Class1 c) : base (c) {
                cl_1 = c.classString;
            }

            public override Func<string, QVoid> Body => (__in) => {
               return cl1;
            };
        }
}
```

Now the error messages are:

```
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core.QVoid' 
error CS1662: Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types
in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
```

Having checked Quantum.Kata.Utils, I realised I need to create a field and a constructor for Class1 which is a base class and also I should override `Func<string, QVoid>` as the Op_1 parameter is string type. But I am not sure if each of these steps individually is done properly?

**Second Update:**

I have changed the previous c# code in first update to the following one:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Common;
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core;
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Simulators;

namespace MyLibrary {
    class Class1 : QuantumSimulator {

        public Class1() { }

        public class Op_1_Impl : Op_1{

            Class1 cl_1;

            public Op_1_Impl (Class1 c) : base (c) {
                cl_1 = c;
            }

            public override Func<string, QVoid> Body => (__in) => {
               return QVoid.Instance;
            };
        }
}
```

Now the error message is the same as the very first one:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors
occurred. (Cannot create an instance of MyLibrary.Op_1 because it is
an abstract class.) ---> System.MemberAccessException: Cannot create
an instance of MyLibrary.Op_1 because it is an abstract class.
```

And also in this new code shouldn't the constructor `public Class1() { }` have a parameter? if so what datatype?

Answer (score 2):

In your code, there is nothing connecting the Q# operation `Op_1` and the C# code that you intend to implement it in `Method_1`.

Q# operations are compiled into classes. To define a C# implementation for a Q# operation with the intrinsic body, you have to define a class that implements the abstract class into which your Q# operation gets compiled; so you would have something like `public class Op_1_Impl : Op_1`.

Getting all the piping right can be a bit tricky (it's a hack, after all!) I would recommend looking at the operation [`GetOracleCallsCount`](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/utilities/Common/Utils.qs#L16) and [its C# implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/utilities/Common/CounterSimulator.cs#L95) to see the exact pieces that have to be in place for it to work.

---

For the updated question, the signature of your method says that it takes string as an input and returns nothing (`QVoid`), but the implementation tries to return a string `cl_1`, so you get a `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core.QVoid'`.

Comment: Thanks Mariia for your answer, I tried to tweak my code but it didn't go through so I have updated my question, could you please check it again, thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer. I did not try to run your code locally, but the error message seems quite straightforward.

Comment: I tried `return QVoid.Instance` before, but received this error messages again: `Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Cannot create an instance of MyLibrary.Op_1 because it is an abstract class.) ---> System.MemberAccessException: Cannot create an instance of MyLibrary.Op_1 because it is an abstract class.`

Comment: I also added the second update with some changes in the code besides changing the return type. Please see Second Update.

Answer (score 1):

To provide a custom C# emulation for your `Op_1` Q# operation, you'll need to replace your Class1.cs with something like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core;


namespace MyLibrary
{
    public partial class Op_1
    {
        public class Native : Op_1
        {
            public Native(IOperationFactory m) : base(m) { }
            public override Func<String, QVoid> Body => (str) =>
            {
                // put your implementation here.
                Console.WriteLine(str);
                return QVoid.Instance;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

You can then run the `Test1Library` using the QuantumSimulator.

That being said, as Mariia said, this is kind of hacky, undocumented functionality that might change in the future, may I ask why you need this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to create an operation that can work with some strings. As in Q# string are just to display messages to the user, so I intend to create  an operation to manipulate strings. Actually this is a long explanation behind why I am doing this... I used your answer in my code  but received this message : `no suitable method found to override`

Comment: I'm certain the code works, but you need to 1. be in the latest version of the QDK (`0.10.1911.1607`); 2. make sure the input parameters type matches in the `Body` definition; 3. make sure the name and namespace of the operations match. If you put your sample in a gist, I can take a quick look.